# DLNA/UPnP: How to respond to SOAP Actions

Tags: http, soap, httprequest, upnp, dlna

I am currently working on a DLNA / UPnP Media Server and while most of it works fine i got some trouble with the following `SOAPAction` Requests:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
HOST: 192.168.1.110:5001
Content-length: 258
Content-Type: text/xml
SOAPAction: "#GetConnectionTypeInfo"
Connection: Close
```

and

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
HOST: 192.168.1.110:5001
Content-length: 250
Content-Type: text/xml
SOAPAction: "#GetStatusInfo"
Connection: Close
```

and

```
POST /upnp/connection_manager HTTP/1.1
HOST: 192.168.1.110:5001
Content-length: 308
Content-Type: text/xml
SOAPAction: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ConnectionManager:1#GetCommonLinkProperties"
Connection: Close
```

and

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
HOST: 192.168.1.110:5001
Content-length: 257
Content-Type: text/xml
SOAPAction: "#GetExternalIPAddress"
Connection: Close
```

last but no least:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
HOST: 192.168.1.110:5001
Content-length: 337
Content-Type: text/xml
SOAPAction: "#GetGenericPortMappingEntry"
Connection: Close
```

I didn't post the Bodys of these Request because the formatting isn't a problem but i don't know how to respond on these Request and can't really find something helpful. To be precise it's not the way on how to respond that makes me wonder but the Content i should provide.
So it would be really nice if someone could explain to me what these request are made for, what a response could look like and / or where i can get some more information (including examples) on these.

Comment: These are WANIPConnection service methods, not something a mediaserver would typically implement...

Comment: alright, i already thought of  this but why are these request send to the media server?

Comment: Either the server claims to implement a WANIPConnection service or the other device is buggy.

Comment: Alright, so i don't have to care about these request and they can be ignored?

Answer (score 1):

Ancient but still unanswered question, so let's try the basics:

> where i can get some more information (including examples) on these.

- Have you read the [Official Specification on UPnP](https://openconnectivity.org/developer/specifications/upnp-resources/upnp/)? That website has everything you need, specially the [full specification PDF](https://openconnectivity.org/upnp-specs/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v2.0-20200417.pdf) and some great [tutorials](https://openconnectivity.org/developer/specifications/upnp-resources/upnp-developer-resources/)

> To be precise it's not the way on how to respond that makes me wonder but the Content i should provide

- Some of those SOAP actions, particularly `GetExternalIPAddress` and `GetGenericPortMappingEntry` are meant for [Internet Gateway Devices](https://openconnectivity.org/developer/specifications/upnp-resources/upnp/internet-gateway-device-igd-v-2-0/), i.e. Routers and such, not Media Servers.
- I wonder *why* you are receiving such requests. How are you advertising your Device via SSDP? What Services you are listing in your root descriptor XML? Those actions are from `WANIPConnection` Service, one I doubt a Media Server wants to implement.

So, before ignoring such requests, you should really investigate *why* you're receiving them in the first place. Likely something is wrong in your SSDP reply.